# python syntax like PHP to store data

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite

I use sqlite3 as database and I have an html form, but I just want to send data when I type on the button , that is to say where put the SQL query in my HTML code ?

please don't give me -1 .... an answer is more explicit than -1

**Html.py**

```
html = '''

<html>
<head>
    <title>- Project -</title>
</head>
<body>

App: ${var1}<br/><br/>

Tix: ${var2}<br/><br/>

Fork: ${var3}<br/><br/>

<form name="sendData" method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py">
    Hobbies: <input type="text" name="hob"><br/><br/>
    Qualities: <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/><br/>
    Defects: <input type="text" name="department"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html> '''
```

**scriptget.py**

```
import cgi, cgitb, os, sys, socket, getpass, platform
import json
import sqlite3

config_file = open("cgi/config.txt", "r")
my_argv = json.load(config_file)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

machine = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])

name = form.getvalue('name')
mail  = form.getvalue('mail')

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
print "<html>"

print "App: :", my_argv[2]
print "<br/><br/>"

print "your name is :", name
print "<br/><br/>" 

print "your mail is :", mail
print "<br/><br/>"

print "</body>"
print "</html>"


conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
c = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

try:
    c.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
except:
     conn.rollback()

     cursor.close()
```

Comment: Better learn some Python web microframework - [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), Bottle, web.py, etc.

Comment: You don't call your query from HTML. Your server-sided script has to perform this task.

Comment: Don't mix HTML, Python, SQL (and CSS, Javascript) in one file.

Comment: Your form sends data to `script.py` - There is the place for code "talking" with database.

Comment: @furas : I can't install framework ( as DJANGO or other), I just want when I type on OK these data are store in my database, but for this I need to create SQL queries , but where in the script ?

Comment: For this first you need some database modul. If you use some ORM you will not have to create SQL query by hand.

Comment: @Matthias : I don't understand, my server is right and run without problems.

Comment: @madness Matthias said: you need python functions to execute SQL query - you can't put SQL query directly in HTML like this: `<h1>SELECT * FROM table</h1>`

Comment: @furas : Yes I get it, but in my file above (scriptGet.py) where can I put my queries...

Comment: Put it with other python functions - like function which use variable `html`.

Comment: Now I see `scriptget.py` - put after line with `mail =`. But you need some python module to use it.

Comment: @furas : can you show me an example please

Comment: What database module do you use ? I can't show you example if I don't know what module do you use.

Comment: example in answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') # your database

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute( "INSERT .... ") #  your SQL query

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

see more in documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Yes I have already create my database since long a long time, and I must put that syntax in scriptGet.py ( which is the script of displaying data) ?

Comment: I have this error : sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

Answer (score 0):

Well, telling from your code you transmit the data from your form (html.py) to *script.py*. In script.py, you just evaluate the data that was transmitted and perform the SQL actions you want (as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)).

So, to make a long story short, you have to perform the SQL actions in *script.py* on the server and not in html.py. The latter isn't possible since html.py won't receive the data sent to *script.py*.

**EDIT:** Okay, now you've elaborated on html.py and scriptGet.py. First, I would suggest using a plain HTML file instead of html.py as long as you're developing. That could be something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>- Project -</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="sendData" method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    Mail: <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/><br/>
    Submit: <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second, you have to put furas' code to use within scriptGet.py (refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for details on how to use SQL):

```
import cgi, cgitb, os, sys, socket, getpass, platform
import json
import sqlite3

config_file = open("cgi/config.txt", "r")
my_argv = json.load(config_file)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

machine = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])

name = form.getvalue('name')
mail = form.getvalue('mail')

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
print "<html>"

print "App: :", my_argv[2]
print "<br/><br/>"

print "your name is :", name
print "<br/><br/>" 

print "your mail is :", mail
print "<br/><br/>"

print "Adding data to SQL database<br/>"
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') # your database
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute( "INSERT .... ") #  your SQL query
conn.commit()
conn.close()

print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

By the way, if you're currently learning Python anyway, you should probably consider Python 3.x instead of 2.x (slightly different syntax). That will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Sure, why not, the more details you provide the better other people can tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, much better. What I don't understand is why you are using html.py - why don't you just use a simple HTML file with the same content? And what exactly is the problem - you don't know how to add the received data to you SQL database from within scriptGet.py? furas told you how that can be achieved.

Comment: that's obligatory to give values when we do an INSERT ?